# Excel Data Connections - getting duplicate entries when there aren't duplicates in the original

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

So you're using Excel data connections to bring a table from one workbook into another. Perhaps you sometimes struggle with the connection seemingly at random deciding that some of the entries in the table are worthy of appearing twice.

Why does this happen?

Example:

Original workbook:

```
A1: ABC
A3: CDE
```

New workbook:

```
A1: ABC
A2: ABC
A3: CDE
A4: CDE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason this can happen, is if you were using autofilter (filter, not sort) in the original workbook when you saved it.

Excel seems to be of the opinion that if the original table is X by X large, the resulting table in the new workbook should also be X by X large. But if some values were hidden in the original workbook, Excel will not always carry these over. This means that the resulting table is no longer going to be X by X large. If that happens, you may experience that Excel figures out all on its own that it can just make duplicates of existing entries until the table is the same size as the original one.

So the table in the original workbook would in reality have looked like this:

```
A1: ABC
A2: 111
A3: CDE
A4: 111
```

If you autofilter to not show values 111 and save the workbook, any updates to the table may now result in the scenario outlined in the question.

In short: always reset filters before saving a workbook that is the source of a data connection.

Comment: When this happened to me, the error was displaced. I have workbook -> workbook -> workbook, and the duplicates only appeared in the final workbook but not in the middle one.